# Query of repeater fields : order by subfield value

Tags: php, wordpress

On a WP website, I have a custom post type ("Clients") with a repeater ("Payments") and 2 subfields : Date and Amount.

I have a query that loops through all the posts and puts the payments in a table.

```
Client 1 - 12/01/2022 - 50€
Client 1 - 23/02/2022 - 170€
Client 2 - 02/12/2021 - 1000€
Client 2 - 07/03/2022 - 4000€
Client 3 - 10/02/2022 - 100€
```

Is there any way to order this table by date of payment ?

Here is my code :

```
    <table>

<?php    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'clients',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
            $post_query->the_post();
        
    $payments = get_field('payments');  
        
      if( $payments ) { 
        foreach( $payments as $payment ) {      
        
        $date = $payment['date'];
        $amount = $payment['amount'];
            ?>
                
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo the_title(); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $amount; ?></td>
  </tr>
            
            <?php   }}}}  ?>
</table>
```

(the code above might contain mistakes ; i took my actual code and simplified it a lot for this post, so i didn't test it)

Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: This might help: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-sorting-a-repeater-field/

Comment: I might be wrong, but this explains how to sort one repeater ? 
In my case, the repeater is in many posts and I want to sort the full output, of all the posts.

Comment: so you want to order posts by an acf date value?

Comment: No, i want to order the table by date of payment, considering that each post may contain 0, 1 or several payments.